# Hide logo in wordpress static front page

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress site. For my Home page i have set a static one.
My home page have only a menu and a full screen animation.

I want a logo that is not visible in homepage. But its visible on all the other pages.

I am using the is_front_page() function. If its false that means we are not in homepage then show the logo else dont show it.

The first time im visiting the site thats works. But when im navigating through the site to my home page again via menu. The home page have the logo visible.

Any tip where is the problem here?

Comment: Please include a link to the site and/or any applicable code. It could be oversight on your end, but it's hard to help if we can't see the issue.

Comment: In dashboard >> setting >> permalinks you can choose custom structure and save changes.

Comment: Ok and changing permalinks how this will help?

Comment: @kak Can you show your site url,,

Comment: i would like too. But its not published yet. So how i can get a link?

Comment: @Samyappa also i think the problem is that header.php where the code is. is not refrshing every time im navigating. So ti keeps the true or fals from the WP function the same until i manually reload the page from brwoser. Its a custom theme. So i dont know if that is on all WP sites or it caused of the theme. The theme developer cant help with this he said.

Comment: @kak how can i help you, if you given site url mean i can inspect element this css problem or function problem!!..,

Comment: I can give you the lines you need to edit in hosts files. Thats the way im curently editing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to hide the logo, it'll be better to hide it using CSS.

However, you need to have `body_class()` added to your `<body>` tag.

```
.home #logo {
    display: none;
}
```

If you still prefer to use server-sided checks and skip printing that HTML altogether, you're doing it correctly already.

For the issue with the logo being visible when you navigate back to the homepage, there might be some issues with the front page settings and the link.

Narrowing down the underlying cause will require more investigation.

Comment: I tried the ccs method. The problem was that when the page was visited for some seconds the logo was visible and then invisible.

Comment: This is probably because the logo's HTML is first loaded and rendered first and the CSS rule above only got applied after that if the CSS rule are defined after the logo. However, I'm more interested in finding out what is causing the logo to reappear if you go back to home page by clicking on links on the menu. Can you share a little bit more about that?

Answer (score 0):

if( ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/') || ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == 'page_slug')){//do stuff only for front page }

Comment: yea its working fine. But still its not fix my problem. Seems If header load once it keeps the same data

Answer (score 0):

Yea im sorry. The code im using is this.

```html
<div class="logo_wrapper" style="margin-top:20px">
<?php if (!is_front_page()){ ?>          
      
<div class="logo1">
  <span id="tk1">Text </span>
  <span id="tk2">Text </span>
  <span id="tk3">Text</span>
</div>
          
<?php }; ?>
```

I cant post a URL of my site couse its not published with nameservers yet

Answer (score 0):

Also i did a check with

```
<?php echo is_front_page(); ?>
```

Starting the site from homepage it return 1. Now visiting other pages it keep returning 1.

```
<?php echo !is_front_page(); ?>
```

Starting the site from homepage it return 0. Now visitting other peges return 1 BUT when revisiting home it keep returning 1.

So it seems that for a reason it run once. Its smthing like static. This code is inside header.php.